# Referencing previous row value using a window function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to be able to reference a previous rows value (which is calculated using previous rows value as well) and do something to that value in the next column.

It would be something like, where "prev" is the value of the most recent computation:

```
select sum(price * qty + prev) over (order by date) from temp
```

Here is example data, note that the 4th row of entry column need reference the 3rd row of realized_pnl:

```
cumu_usd    cumu_stock  entry       realized_pnl
100         1           100         0
300         5           60          0
150         3           50          (150/2 - 60) * 2 = 30
200         4           (200+30)/4  30

entry = (cumu_usd +realized_pnl) / cumu_stock
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your question is confusing because the pseudo-code has nothing to do with the SQL code.

Comment: @GordonLinoff hey Gordon, is the problem clearer now? added example

Comment: Not clear yet, is `realized_pnl` an input or it is calculated in a way?

Comment: realized_pnl is calculated as the (change of cumu_usd / change of cumu_stock - entry) * previous entry ... ie it is calculated using inputs from ROW2

Comment: basically, entry is computed based on realized_pnl value, but realized_pnl is also compute based on previous entry values ..

Comment: Have you tried recursive CTE?

Comment: yes I have - and it works . but is there a way to do it with counter / for loop?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just use a function with a cursor?

Comment: @DonR i am pretty new to psql, do you have a link you can send?

Comment: Does this help? https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-cursor/

Comment: You might be able to use the lag function, if there were something to order by.  Your pseudo-code references a date column, but that doesn't exist in the table.  How do you figure out which row is the previous row?

Comment: @Jeremy .. looks like lag wouldn't help because of  2 calculated columns cross referencing each other lag.

Comment: @Serg Thanks, I missed that.  I agree that a recursive CTE is probably the best option.